# What would be the minimal keys of this relation?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

R(ABCDE)

List of FDs

`AB`→`C`,
`BC`→`D`,
`CD`→`E`,
`DE`→`A`

Now, we would find the minimal keys:

Since, we don’t see `B` on the left hand side, we will start with `B`.

Now,

### {B}+

B

Nothing comes. So, we will have to add another attribute with B.

Let’s start with A.

### `{AB}+`

`AB`
`=> ABC [AB -> C]`
`=> ABCD [BC -> D]`
`=> ABCDE [CD -> E]`. So, AB is a minimal key.

### `{BC}+`

`BC`
`=> BCD [BC -> D]`
`=> BCDE [CD -> E]`
`=> ABCDE [DE -> A]`. So, BC is a minimal key.

### {BD}+

`BD`    Nothing is possible further. So, BD is not a minimal key.

### {BE}+

`BE`        Nothing is possible further. So, BE is not a minimal key.

Now, I have the follwing questions:

1. Does this relation have more minimal keys?
2. What are they? Are they BDE, BDA? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another key in addition to `AB` and `BC` is `BDE`. You can see this if you calculate:

```
BDE+ = BDE
       ABDE  (using DE → A)
       ABCDE (using AB → C)
```

And there are no other keys.